# What does it mean to find a particle in a range at a given value?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, probability

> Find the probability of finding the electron in the range $\Delta r = 0.02a_0$ at (a) $r = a_0$ and (b) $r = 2a_0$ for the state $n = 2$, $l = 0$, $m = 0$ in hydrogen.

I don't understand the first part of the question. I think it is saying that there is, let's say, a range from $0$ to some value on a convenient $r$-axis. It starts at $r=0$ and stops at $r=0.02a_0$. We want to find the probability of finding a particle at $r=a_0$. But based on how I've illustrated the $r$-axis, $r=a_0$ is *way* past $r=0.02a_0$, is it not?

Comment: It's asking you to compute the probability of the particle being in the interval $[r-\Delta r,r+\Delta r]$ (or the interval with half that width, it should make that clearer).

Answer (score 1):

If $\psi(x)=\Psi(x,t=0)$ is the wave function of a particle/system at $t=0$, then $\psi^*(x)\psi(x)$ is the probability density (at $t=0$) and $\psi^*(x)\psi(x) dx $ is the probability of finding the particle within an interval of $dx$ around position $x$.  But this doesn't give us any number because $dx$ is arbitrarily small. To find the probability of being within some *finite* interval, we integrate the probability density around a specific $x$ value:

$$P(b\pm\epsilon)=\int\limits_{b-\epsilon}^{b+\epsilon}\psi^*(x)\psi(x) dx$$

If you need to find the time-dependent probability and $\psi(x)$ is not an eigenstate, it's a bit more complicated.